# How do i encrypt ldap password?

Tags: ldap, novell

I am new to LDAP and is using it with com.novell.ldap.

I have a login page where the user is entering the username and password. My job here is to save the encrypted password in LDAP.

how can i do?

Answer (score 0):

The userPassword attribute (which is used to store a password in a user entry in LDAP) is usually hashed by the LDAP server itself. You do not encrypt passwords to store them.